# How is the number of totalBits, required, computed?

Tags: c#, geneticsharp

Using GeneticSharp, I started working on some optimizations in order to lower the computational power, required. For that purpose I try to lower the `totalBits` but it does not seem apparent how the required number bits is computed given

- precision of input variable and
- possible variable range.

Can someone please comment on how the total number bits, required, are computed. Ideally I want to set the `totalBits` parameter as function of chosen precision and value range.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four arguments of FloatingPointChromosome's constructor are:

- The minimum values of numbers inside the chromosome.
- The maximum values of numbers inside the chromosome. It means the maximum number that a chromosome can represent (solution).
- The total bits used to represent each number. For example, if your maximum value is 998, so 10 bits is what you need.

> GeneticSharp will warn you if you try to use a total bits that cannot
>   hold a number inside your floating point chromosome.

- The number of fraction (scale or decimal) part of the number.

More info: https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/issues/42

Comment: Sorry but that does not even touch on the question at all. Which parameters are required in a constructor is perfectly apparent. How do you get from 998 to 10 bits and which exact variable does your example "maximum value" represent?